# SVG and CSS: Animating pattern background

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a cross-browser animation with SVG:

**HTML:**

```
 <svg width="100" height="100">
                  <defs>
                    <pattern id="imgt1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
                      <image class="animateMove" xlink:href="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/sports/sportsgames/pics/cricket_ball.jpg" width="500" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
                    </pattern>
                  </defs>
                  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#imgt1)"></circle>
                </svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
svg:hover .animateMove{
    transform:translate(-10px,-20px);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-10px,-20px);
    -moz-transform:translate(-10px,-20px);
    -o-transform:translate(-10px,-20px)
}

.animateMove {     
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:-moz-transform .5s ease-out;
 -o-transition:-o-transform .5s ease-out;
 transition:transform .5s ease-out;
 }
```

This basically renders a Circle and masks an image inside.
If the user hovers the image, it's origin is translated.

It perfectly works in Chrome and Safari (so WebKit seems to work), but fails in all other browsers.

For better explanation, see following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RX74Z/3/

If I animate the picture directly (see http://jsfiddle.net/RX74Z/6/), it also works with firefox but the mask (indeed) will not be shown :D.

I guess the "fill" causes trouble in all other browsers. Is there another approach I could use to create a similar effect?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could get this working perfectly cross-browser with pure css. I would expect you would need to use script. Look at snap.svg. Here's a demo very close in spirit to what you're attempting: http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe

Comment: mhhh, is there something else I could use to mask an image inside a circle (instead  using a fill pattern)

Comment: Well, you could also use svg clip-path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking. But why not just transition background-position on :hover? Is there a reason why you need svg here? Just draw a circle using CSS border radius. Maybe you're simplifying for the sake of a demo, but your example is readily achievable in regular old CSS3, without script, and probably with better fallback support.

Comment: yeah, it's a simplified example, but I guess this is the only solution currently cross-browser working. I will stick with that. thank you

Comment: Snap is cross-browser too, IE9+.